# create jenkins image with docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I want to create a jenkins image with a dockerfile.
Docker is running (tried it with the hello-world image).

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essentials
USER jenkins
```

I want to build an image with this command

```
sudo docker build -t "jenkins_master" .
```

But i always get this error:

```
    E: Unable to locate package build-essentials
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install build-essentials' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

i've tried:

- sudo service docker restart
- sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

But nothing works. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remember that these commands are running within the Docker container itself when you are building your Docker image. Therefore running commands on your local machine is unlikely to resolve the issue.

I think the package is called `build-essential` and not `build-essentials` (notice you have the extra 's' on the end of the package name).

Therefore changing your Dockerfile to read:

```
FROM jenkins:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
USER jenkins
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)

> Always combine RUN apt-get update with apt-get install in the same 
>   RUN statement, for example
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y package-bar
>
> (...)
>
> Using apt-get update alone in a RUN statement causes caching issues
>   and subsequent apt-get install instructions fail.

Comment: i changed it (see edited entry above) but i got the same error message